# Java: Changing scanner.nextDouble accepting a dot as decimal-seperator OR writing doubles with a comma in a file

Tags: java, file-io, format, java.util.scanner

```
File myfile = new File("Example.txt");              // the text of myFile looks like this: "3,0"
Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(myFile);             
Double double1 = scanner1.nextDouble();             // reading "3,0" - everything okay

try (Writer filewriter = new FileWriter(myFile)) {
            filewriter.write(double1);              // writing "3.0" - inconsistent but works for me
            filewriter.flush();                     // (which obviously will not work for Java)
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println("oops");
        }

Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(myFile);
Double double2 = scanner2.nextDouble();             // There it is: "java.util.InputMismatchException"
```

My question is, how to make it write doubles with a seperation-comma in a file OR how to make scanner read doubles with a separation-dot. Both would be okay.

I already tried to use objects of DecimalFormat and so on, but it didn't change anything for me. That's why I would be very happy about some answers... Thank you for everybody trying.

Comment: The Javadoc for `Scanner` explains how it parses floating point numbers. And, assuming you actually meant `filewriter.write(double1.toString())`, the Javadoc for `Double#toString` also explains how the value is serialized. Use a different formatter if you want a different format.

Answer (score 1):

To Write to the file, convert the data value to be written with a comma instead of a decimal point:

```
filewriter.write(String.valueOf(double1).replace(".", ","));
```

To Read the file and convert the data values:

```
// Create a File object to use in Scanner reader.
File myFile = new File("myfile.txt");
// Make sure file exists.
if (!myFile.exists()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The following file path can not be found!" + 
                            System.lineSeparator() + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
    
// Try With Resourses used here to auto-close reader.
try (Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(myFile)) {
    // Read in each numerical token from file...
    while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
        // Declare a Double variable initialized to null
        Double double2 = null;
        /* Read in a token and remove any numerical block charaters
           for example, 3.456,33 the point is common in European 
           countries as a thousands separator and the comma as a 
           decimal point). We also convert the comma decimal separator 
           to a dot to accomodate your local and the double data type.  */
        String dblStrg = scanner2.next().replaceAll("[\\.\\s']", "").replaceAll(",", ".");
        /* Make sure the numerical String value is 
           in fact a string representation of an 
           Integer or a double data type.      */
        if (dblStrg.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            /* It is so convert the numerical value 
               to a double data type.          */
            double2 = Double.parseDouble(dblStrg);
        }
        /* If however the numerical value read from file
           is not a valid Integer or double then inform
           User as such.         */
        if (double2 == null) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Double Number! (" + dblStrg + ")");
        } 
        // Display the contents of the double type variable.
        else {
            System.out.println(double2);
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```